# why spring boot filter call twice?

Tags: java, spring-boot

my spring boot version is 1.5.4,here is my config code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@RestController
@ServletComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("test");
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

here is my servlet filter code

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class LogFilter implements Filter {


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("LogFilter");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

//init and destroy
```

When i visit http://localhost:8080/ console is out print

```
LogFilter
test
LogFilter <----the second time
```

why call filter twice?Spring boot Why do this? Is there a relevant document or source reference?where I want him to call once, how can i do it?

update: thx all the problem has been solved

Comment: I suggest using loggers instead of System.out.prinln :) Try accessing with https - would it still be the same? Maybe your tomcat forces https and rewrites the request?

Comment: If your problem is being solved, mark the answer as a solution or post an answer yourself.

Comment: If you want your filter to only be called once per request, extend `OncePerRequestFilter` instead of `Filter`.

Answer (score 19):

Please check if the class where in you had defined your filter was a bean or a regular class. In case it is a bean/component then you do not have to specifically register the filter in your security configuration for eg by using

```
http.addFilterBefore(new YourFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).
```

By registering a bean additionally as mentioned, the same filter will get executed twice.

Comment: thank you, that was exactly my case. Should be on the top as this is the only possible reason when you're curtain on things like calling URL twice

Comment: Seem like it works for me. Before I added the filter with the injected bean. Then I change to regular class like your example. But i'm curious why it called twice if I use the injected bean. Do you know the reason behind?

Answer (score 12):

If you try to log the request url from doFilter method, you'll see why. Here is I create new SpringBoot project and test with doFilter method.

```
    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    logger.info(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
}
```

Well, the two urls are

```
http://localhost:8080/index
http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico
```

Comment: This is correct, in my case for authentication when it failed, second url that was called is /error.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two common reasons for this behavior:

1. the spring application context is loaded twice by your application
2. A redirect is causing a second request on the endpoint

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the question is in documentation:

> The doFilter method of the Filter is called by the container each time a **request/response** pair is passed through the chain due to a client request for a resource at the end of the chain.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

Comment: I don't think that's the reason why its being called twice. See Yongzhao's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Extending answer from @wrathtoliar

If your filter is invoking Spring bean. Make an autowired variable instead of manual java instantiation.

```
@Autowired
private YourFilter yourFilter;

http.addFilterBefore(yourFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security doesn’t guarantee the filter won’t be called more than once, so we have to take care of this ourselves. The easiest way is to implement the filter using the OncePerRequestFilter class

Here is an example;

```java
public class AuthenticationLoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationLoggingFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String requestId = request.getHeader("Request-Id");
        logger.info("Successfully authenticated request with id " + requestId);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```